# Как организовать подгрузку материалов knockoutjs?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, html, javascript, knockoutjs

Всем привет! Допустим нужно сделать постраничную навигацию, как AJAX подгрузку, при клике на кнопку, на первый взгляд это кажется элементарно: сделать привязку к массиву материалов и подгружать их при клике. Но что делать, если с самой загрузки страницы должны быть загружены первые 10 материалов, а потом подгружать новые. Возможно ли как-то на стороне нокаута добавлять изначально загруженные элементы в список, и как это все должно происходить? Надеюсь все понятно, если нет - спрашивайте, что не понятно в вопросе и я уточню.

Comment: Происходит так - у вас должна быть объявлена переменная javascript, которая хранит изначально число 1 - то бишь первые 10 ( 1 + 10) элементов массива. При клике увеличиваете это значение на 10 и подгружаете данные. По ходу так.

Comment: Этот ответ вообще никак не относится к вопросу.

Comment: А, ну да, че-то подумал, что нокаут - это как в боксе.))